# How do you identify provisioning profile names from their UUID

Tags: ios, xcode

When you create provisioning profiles in the provisioning portal and set which ones to use in XCode its always done using a human readable name. But when there is a build problem involving profiles/signing the error message gives the UUID of the troublesome profile, not its human readable name. So how do you find out which profile a UUID in a build error message is referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally just grep -i UUID in the provision profile directory, then vim the file to find the name, but here's an attempt at a script.

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Name' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/UPPER_CASE_UDID_HERE.mobileprovision)`

p.s. seems like something mdfind might be good at.

Comment: what when I didn't have plistbuddy (I don't know, why, cause I have xcode installed)? Could you post your grep based script?